# SQL Join on timestamps where you only take the first/oldest result

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

Let's say I have two tables:

`Table #1` `t1`

```
ID | Col1 | MeasureTime         | Parameter_ID
----------------------------------------------
1  | abc  | 2020-11-11 07:00:00 | 1
2  | abc  | 2020-11-11 08:00:00 | 1
```

`Table #2` `t2`

```
ID | Parameter_ID | Col2 | ValidFrom
----------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | xyz  | 2020-11-11 06:30:00
2  | 1            | def  | 2020-11-11 07:30:00
```

I want to join both tables using the `Parameter_ID` and I want to have a 1:1 relationship. The `ValidFrom` from `t2` is the time that this parameter becomes valid. But unfortunately there is no `ValidTo` but rather I have to check that I join with the first `Parameter_ID` from `t2` where the `ValidFrom` is valid.

So I want to have this result:

`Table #3` `t3`

```
ID | Col1 | MeasureTime         | Parameter_ID | ValidFrom | Col2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | abc  | 2020-11-11 07:00:00 | 1            | 06:30:00  | xyz
2  | abc  | 2020-11-11 08:00:00 | 1            | 07:30:00  | def
```

but if I would do a simple:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON t1.PARAMETER_ID = t2.PARAMETER_ID AND t1.Measuretime >= t2.ValidFrom
```

I would get:

`Table #3` `t3`

```
ID | Col1 | MeasureTime         | Parameter_ID | ValidFrom | Col2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | abc  | 2020-11-11 07:00:00 | 1            | 06:30:00  | xyz
2  | abc  | 2020-11-11 08:00:00 | 1            | 06:30:00  | xyz
3  | abc  | 2020-11-11 08:00:00 | 1            | 07:30:00  | def
```

where I actually don't want to have `ID` `2`.

Hope my problem becomes clear. I could think of something like "if there are multiple results from t2, order by ValidFrom ASC and take only the first". But unfortunately I'm not really sure how to do this with SQL. Maybe there is also a more elegant solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest generated a `valid_to` using `lead()`.  Then use a `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.valid_from, t2.col2
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             lead(valid_from) over (partition by parameter_id order by valid_from) as valid_to
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.parameter_id = t2.parameter_id and
        t1.MeasureTime >= t2.valid_from and
        (t1.MeasureTime < t2.valid_to or t2.valid_to is null);
```

Although you way that you are willing to just line up the values in the two tables, it sounds like the correct solution is to get the row from `table2` whose date range includes the `table1` date.

Comment: While the other answers were correct as well (using ROW_NUMBER()) I liked your solution the most! Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number()

```
select a.* from 

(SELECT *, row_number()over(partition by Col1,MeasureTime order by MeasureTime) rn
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON t1.PARAMETER_ID = t2.PARAMETER_ID AND t1.Measuretime >= t2.ValidFrom
) a were a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expand your original query using `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT T1.*, T2.VALID_FROM, T2.COL2,
        ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T2.VALID_FROM DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN
  FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.PARAMETER_ID = T2.PARAMETER_ID
                 AND T1.MEASURETIME >= T2.VALIDFROM)
WHERE RN = 1
```